# IntMap traverseWithKey faster than mapWithKey?

Tags: performance, haskell, parallel-processing

I was reading [this part](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/parallel-and-concurrent/9781449335939/ch04.html#:%7E:text=Example%3A%20Shortest%20Paths%20in%20a%20Graph) of Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell, and found the sequential version of the program to be far slower than the parallel one with one core:

Sequential:

```
$ cabal run fwsparse -O2 --ghc-options="-rtsopts" -- 1000 800 +RTS -s
...
Total   time   11.469s  ( 11.529s elapsed)
```

Parallel:

```
$ cabal run fwsparse1 -O2 --ghc-options="-rtsopts -threaded" -- 1000 800 +RTS -s -N1
...
Total   time    4.906s  (  4.988s elapsed)
```

According to the book, the sequential one should be slightly faster than the parallel one (if it runs on a single core).

The only difference in the two programs was this function:

Sequential:

```
update g k = Map.mapWithKey shortmap g
```

Parallel:

```
update g k = runPar $ do
    m <- Map.traverseWithKey (\i jmap -> spawn (return (shortmap i jmap))) g
    traverse get m
```

Since the `spawn` function uses `deepseq`, I initially though it had something to do with strictness but the use of `force` didn't change the performance of the sequential program.

Finally, I managed to get the sequential one work faster:

```
$ cabal run fwsparse -O2 --ghc-options="-rtsopts" -- 1000 800 +RTS -s
...
Total   time    3.891s  (  3.901s elapsed)
```

by changing the `update` function to this:

```
update g k = runIdentity $ Map.traverseWithKey (\i jmap -> pure $ shortmap i jmap) g
```

Why does using `traverseWithKey` in the `Identity` monad speed up performance? I checked the IntMap source code but couldn't figure out the reason.

Is this a bug or the expected behaviour?

(Also, this is my first question on StackOverflow so please tell me if I'm doing anything wrong.)

EDIT:
As per Ismor's comment, I turned off optimization (using `-O0`) and the sequential program runs in 19.5 seconds with either `traverseWithKey` or `mapWithKey`, while the parallel one runs in 21.5 seconds.

- Why is `traverseWithKey` optimized to be so much faster than `mapWithKey`?
- Which function should I use in practice?

Comment: um... interesting. Can you test again but without optimization? (i.e. the `-02` flag). Maybe, the compiler is doing a very agressive optimization here due to inlining. (I have no idea, It is just a guess.. haha)

Comment: @Ismor I ran the program with no optimization (`-O0` flag) and the sequential program now runs in 19.5 seconds using `mapWithKey` or `traverseWithKey`, while the parallel one runs in 21.5 seconds on one core. Optimization does seem to have something to do with it, I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: In the source code, `mapWithKey` is marked as `NOINLINE` but `traverseWithKey` is marked with `INLINE`... why so much difference? I don't know. GHC is inscrutable in its ways... Inlining provides some performance benefits, but I wouldn't expect that much... Maybe, when inlining `traverseWithKey` it triggers even more inlining optimizations. I hope someone with more knowledge about this can help

Comment: @Ismor Nice observation! I didn't notice that earlier. According to comments in the source code for the ordinary `map` in the Prelude, the `NOINLINE` serves to allow the `RULE` pragmas to fire to fuse multiple traversals. I assume the same thing applies to `mapWithKey`.  
I'm not sure if inlining is solely responsible for such a huge speed up though, so I'd appreciate if someone more experienced could confirm this or add to it.